# How to make designs to have realistic woven/knitted texture

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, texture, effects, image-editing

I would like to turn any design in a way that it looks woven/knitted such as this image below:

[image: Example]

Then I attempted to recreate this effect for any design that I want but the result wasn't satisfying. So the first step that I did was to find the original image: [image]

With the design layer selected, I then went into Filter Gallery and applied "Cutout" filter onto the design with this setting: [image]

After that, I noticed the example image looks a bit dim so I went ahead and decreased the saturation of the image:[image]

Then I went to the internet to find myself a woven/knitted texture so that I can applied it on top of the design. With a texture chosen, I immediately extracted the texture's shadow using alpha channel and put it on top of the design and lower its opacity to make them blend in together: [image]

When everything is done, I'm left with this result that still doesn't look anywhere close to the example image: [image]

I'm sure that there's much more you can do to achieve the desired result but with my limited ability in photoshop, this is as far as I could go. I tried looking up tutorials on youtube and google but to no avail so I decided to come to the forum for help. Does anyone know what should be done or any techniques that could help me achieve the same or as close as possible result to that of the sample image? That would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is a pretty decent result to be honest, and I like it better than the original example. Perhaps it's really just down to the choice of texture image itself.  You might also want to try using different blending modes (in the layers panel), rather than opacity.

Comment: The reason why I want my design to look like the original is because I'm trying to make a woven blanket mockup with design embedded on and I want it to look as realistic as possible.

Comment: Have you tried a decent greyscale woven texture and [Displacement Maps](https://www.google.com/search?q=displacement+maps+photoshop&oq=displacment+maps&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0i10l9.6920j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I guess you are not going to print it on a single piece of textile material. What's your textile fabrication process to put together areas which have different colors and the seams between them? Knowing that is the starting point of suggestions of plausible mockup images. Do not use advanced textile fabrication terms, but plain English - that's because most of us know nothing of textile fabrication terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Your technique looks good. I suggest finding additional source image textures. Use these different textures for different areas. Mask one texture to the inside of the ears and a different to the shadows, etc. I think a little more variation will go a long way.

Alternatively: have you searched for PhotoShop actions that create a similar effect? There are likely many free and paid actions that you could use and/or adapt or recreate for your specific wants and needs.
For instance:
Embroidery Actions for PS
https://elements.envato.com/realistic-embroidery-2-photoshop-actions-TTM5KU
or
https://graphicriver.net/item/embroidered-logo-badge-photoshop-action/15284525
or
https://graphicriver.net/item/photoshop-stitch-creative-toolkit/21212746

For Knitting specific PS actions:
https://graphicriver.net/item/knitting-cs3-photoshop-action/18948973
or
https://graphicriver.net/item/knitted-style-photoshop-actions/10067987

or this Free one from Adobe for an Ugly Christmas Sweater PS action
https://creativecloud.adobe.com/cc/discover/article/ugly-christmas-sweater-in-a-few-clicks-with-a-free-photoshop-action?locale=en
(Please note, I have no association with any of these links, they are just actions that I found from Google searches that may be of inspiration to you).